# Origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy( Proxy Added)

Tags: angular

I am using Angular as a front end which is connecting to a Web API on the internet.
I am currently facing an error: [network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxCuf.png)

Comment: Please copy the text of the error into your post, instead of linking an image.

Comment: Share your proxy conf....

Answer (score 1):

Your backend needs to add localhost:4200 as an origin.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your proxy config to take a look otherwise maybe you are missing the `"changeOrigin": true,`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using live **`API`** for **`local testing`** then you need to enable **`CORS`** extension. and then after you can call that **`API`** ..

**Here is the process to install and enable `CORS` extension**

> First type **cors extennsion chrome**

[image: Type like this in google]

> Then open this link
> Then click on **`Add to chrome`**

[image]

> After add that extension you will find **C:** icon like this image..
> [image]

> Now just click on icon **C:** and enable it.
> [image]

> **`NOW call your API`**